# How to send custom order to a contract with Metamask

Tags: metamask

I'm trying to figure out how I can send custom interaction with contract using Metamask.

I am trying to approve a token spend on MM.finance before it goes live so I'll be ready but their website won't allow it by default. I know there must be some way, as I saw some TX getting the approval and using the exact same input data as is used by this website to approve other tokens.

This is the kind of TX sent for approval I found on another wallet:

[image]

And the tx I am trying to copy is the following :
https://cronoscan.com/tx/0x20c539aa4dfa779a9c63bc96878ead96975c584e154ce9e7d26e598b28f4e8f6

Any idea?

Edit:

Thanks to Bru53001 for his answer. It looks great but it is still too complex/vague for a noob like me.

Do I need to go to a service like remix to push a contract? (I just read about it but never used it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the token page on the block explorer, Cronoscan in this case, first. For verified contracts, you can go to the "Contract/Code" -> "Write Contract" tabs. From there, find the `approve` function, paste in the MM.finance(or any other router address-for MM.finance it is `0x145677FC4d9b8F19B5D56d1820c48e0443049a30`) router address for `spender`, and for maxing out the allowance, use `0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff` as the amount(max uint256).

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm trying to follow your steps but going to : 
https://cronoscan.com/address/0xd8eb4845b094e05f4d01d7bb3468238076f744f1#code
I saw the code in the unreadable form. I used the decode function and searched but found no approve in it. 

Do you mind being a little more specific for someone who has no idea?

Many thanks!

Comment: Also when you say paste  the aprove function in mm.finance, do you mean paste it on the mm.finance/ web address?

Comment: I mean the MM.finance **router** contract address. Each DEX nowadays seems to have a "router" that facilitates trades. You need to approve the router to spend your tokens. As I said in my original post, the address you need for this case is `0x145677FC4d9b8F19B5D56d1820c48e0443049a30`. 

For your other problem, you can copy one of the approval transactions' raw data(scroll down, view as-->original), and send it to the token address via Metamask. You can enable hex data in Metamask from Settings-->Advanced.